# The Simpsons Hit and Run doesn't start on Windows 7

Tags: technical-issues, windows-7, backwards-compatibility, the-simpsons-hit-and-run

And I really really REALLY want to play this game. I've tried everything available on the first results of Google to no avail.

The best advice is to tweak the compatibility settings to Windows XP or 98 and start with administrator privileges. But the game just doesn't want to start up!

Can you help me? I remember there was a utility, an actual administrator compatibility toolkit which I used when I had Windows XP to be able to run Extreme G2, but it was too technical for me to tweak settings. Is there an equivalent for Windows 7? Remember this is the starter version so it doesn't come with virtual machine with Windows XP.

I don't know if it helps but my rig is an Acer Aspire laptop using AMD fusion processor C-50. It's a dual core system.

Comment: Can you provide more details about the actual error you're getting?

Comment: That is the major problem, The farthest I was able to go was the game starting on a window and immediately reporting to microsoft that the game stoped working, i don't get an error message and I don't even see the company logos of the game. I get absolutely nothing.

Comment: Open up the EventLog using Start -> Run and type 'eventvwr' and press Enter. In the Windows Logs -> Applications section, there may be more information about the error. And are you using a 64bit Windows?

Comment: I'll do that arriving home, thanks. And no, I'm using Windows 7 starter, starter is always 32bit.

Comment: I run that thing but it doesn't shot anything related, I don't know exactly were to look.

Comment: Can you provide technical details from report sent to Microsoft?

Comment: According to [this thread](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/older-games-work-win-7-a-t4039329.html) people have got it working ... maybe ask in there.

Comment: It's not so much that they got it working as it simply worked out of the box for the original poster on that thread. `Added Simpsons Hit and Run to list. This game runs remarkably well in Win 7 64 Bit and the graphics can be set fairly high, I have it running at 1280 x 1024 for starters and it will probably go higher.`

Comment: I had a similar problem with Extreme G-2 (an original game for Nintendo 64). I solved the problem by using a Nintendo 64 emulator. This is the only way that I could get the game to play.

Answer (score 3):

In compatibility settings, check win 98/ME compatibility, disable visual themes and desktop composition, and you should be good to go.

Comment: I already tried that. Didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

How about...

Installing Ubuntu with Wubi (doesn't destroy your windows install)
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/windows-installer

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide

And using WINE
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine

Because it should work -
http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=10480

Answer (score 2):

You are likely seeking [Application Compatibility Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=24da89e9-b581-47b0-b45e-492dd6da2971&displaylang=en) and its associated [documentation resources](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/aa905066)

Comment: Well that's certainly the tool I mentiond I could need, but still, the matter of the question is entirly different, I'm looking for a solid solution.

Answer (score 2):

you may want to try downloading a free virtual machine such as one of the VMware versions, and then putting xp on the virtual machine and install hit and run onto the VMware

Comment: This is a 3D game - it'll run like a dog in a VM, if it all.

Comment: @AlanB It's an *old* 3D game. I've run old 3D games in a VM, and it's often fine. Sure, playing *Morrowind* with the 3rd-party graphics enhancer DLL-injector with all settings maxed out was a little bit jittery in the VM, but I could play it in its original form just fine. :)

Comment: Good to know! FWIW, since this question was asked I installed it on my Win 7 64-bit laptop from the original discs and it works fine without doing anything other than running as administrator.

Answer (score 2):

What directory did you install it in?

Windows Vista and Windows 7 have restrictions on access to the 'Program Files' or 'Program Files (x86)' folder (this where 64-bit Windows installs 32-bit programs), which may cause incompatibilities with older games. Install it in a non-Program Files directory, like at `C:\Games\GameNameWithoutSpaces` folder. (Some old games also do not like being installed in directories with spaces in their names.)

Also, try running the game as an administrator (right click the game's .EXE file and then go to Properties->Compatibility).

Also, check if you have the latest version of DirectX 9.0c, the June 2010 update (needed by old games). As far as I know, some components of DirectX 9 is not included by default with Vista and Windows 7 (even if DirectX 10 and DirectX 11 is already installed). You can get it here:
Standalone Installer
http://www.filehippo.com/download_directx/
Web Installer
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=35

Also, the usual advice when a game doesn't run also still applies: Update your videocard drivers.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Lucas' Simpsons Hit & Run Mod Launcher](https://donutteam.com/releases/view/lucas-mod-launcher).
The launcher adds native widescreen and borderless fullscreen support, some bug fixes and intro video skip among other features (all optional).

Comment: Know if this launcher will also work for this other issue? [The simpsons hit and run for pc takes too long to load?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/332245/4797)

Comment: @galacticninja I don't, sorry. I can't recall encountering loading times out of the ordinary and I played from a 7200 RPM HDD (at best, may have been slower). I nearly finished the game and I'd guess two seconds at most.

Answer (score -3):

Change your Screen Resolutions to a Resolution that was standard back in the 90/00 dudes. 800x600 and you wont have any issues with the most of the games.