# The simpsons hit and run for pc takes too long to load?

Tags: the-simpsons-hit-and-run

The simpsons hit and run for pc takes too long to load on my PC, the loading screen takes too long - even if I can bear the loading screen, the slow loading sometimes makes the game unplayable, you can see that the game fails to load the city in the image below.
[image: The simpsons hit and run for pc takes too long to load]

I'm using Windows 8.1, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set compatibility mode for Windows 98 like [123iamking's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/332246/198960) is an easy & simple way. But each time you run the game, it [requires Administrator right](https://superuser.com/questions/177840/run-a-program-in-compatibility-mode-without-administrator-privileges).

---

So here is a way you can run the game without Administrator right: set affinity to 1 core with cmd.

**Step 1:**
Create a bat file called `Simpsons.bat` in the game directory.

In the file `Simpsons.bat`, use [affinity cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7760105/4608491):

```
start /affinity 1 Simpsons.exe
```

[image: The Simpsons affinity bat]

**Step 2:** Edit the game shortcut so that it run Simpsons.bat instead of Simpsons.exe
[image]

Comment: Since the source code was leaked I had the chance to spot the bug and fix it :) they used a unlock and lock statement on a mutex on the main thread without waiting for the other loading threads to take over

Answer (score 2):

Just run the game in compatibility mode for Windows 98
[image: Compatibility mode for Win98]

Thanks to [Sargon for recommend this in a Youtube comment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=szUmXl8Gdr8&lc=UggmWlEBJvl793gCoAEC)

> I recommend just running it in Windows 98 compatibility mode. It will
>   automatically set affinity to 1 core and you won't have to do it
>   manually every single time. Sure it's just 1 core, not 2, but this is
>   such an old game that it won't matter.